# Creating a local .json file in Extjs

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I want to create/save a .json file locally in Extjs with information from the DOM. Usually to POST, DELETE, GET or PUT .json query packets, the following method is used;

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: GlobalInfo.apiURL + 'api/grades/postsub',
    method: 'POST',
    params: {
        SubjectName: newSubjectName,
        SkillID: newSubjSkill
    },
    success: function(){
        Ext.MessageBox.alert('Status', 'Success');
    },
    failure: function() {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Status', 'You failed me! :o');
    }

});
```

Is there a similar method I can use to create a local .json file on the hard drive of the user when they click a 'Save' button for example?

Comment: The [FileWriter API](http://caniuse.com/#feat=filesystem).

Comment: Thank you for that but I require a solution that is compatible with more older versions of browsers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create a store/model which uses a client proxy.  Ext has a few built in client proxies.

- Local storage
- In memory
- Session

If none of these work for your target browsers, then you will likely need to write your own.

[The Sencha docs on proxies should help](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Proxy)